# How do I loop through this JSON when array has static name?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a JSON that for the purpose I have simplified as below

```
{
    "status": "Ok",
    "error": null,
    "result": {
        "AE": [
            {
                "storeCode": "AE1434"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to loop through the JSON and search for a specific country, the `"AE"` in my example is a country code so there will also be `"SE"` and `"US"` etc so that I then can get into that specific array and get the `storeCode` and work with that later in my code

I am stuck cause I don't know how to do the `foreach` when the top level key, in this case `"AE"` changes all the time so to say.

Comment: How are you parsing/deserializing the json?

Comment: I am calling a WebApi that returns it so I am storing it as a JObject but I need to get to the storeCode and change it, actually remove the AE in front so that the object looks the same as before but each storeCode does NOT have the country code in front of it

Comment: That is the actual JSON, and you can see the array is under AE in this case, the problem is I dont how to get to that array and loop through it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are searching for specific country and do not want to Deserialize the Json, you could use

```
JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(json);
if(jobj["result"]["AE"]!=null) 
{
    var aeList = jobj["result"]["AE"];
    foreach(var item in aeList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item["storeCode"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the json keys can have different names `"AE"`, `"US"`, etc you can model this part of the json using a `Dictionary`. The following classes model the json you've shown:

```
public class Properties
{
    public string StoreCode { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Error { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, List<Properties>> Result { get; set; }
}
```

Once you've deserialized the json, you can iterate over the dictionary keys and the list within.

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(json);
// iterate over dictionary keys
foreach (var key in result.Result.Keys) 
{
    // inner list
    var properties = result.Result[key];
    foreach (var property in properties)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(key + ": " + property.StoreCode);
    }
}
```

[Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/eAb7rh)

<sup>Note: my class names are just an example, change them to a more descriptive name that suits your situation better</sup>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop through the country codes you can do it like this:

```
string json = File.ReadAllText("./JSONTextFile.txt");

JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(json);

JToken resultToken = jObject["result"];

foreach(var child in resultToken.Children())
{
    JProperty jProperty = (JProperty)child;
    string name = jProperty.Name;

    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```

Assuming your JSON is in the JSONTextFile.txt file and you are using the Newtonsoft JSON library.